# Is the yellow warning tab in React Native supposed to show even after fixing the issue in Expo CLI?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I was following a course on React Native with this simple code:

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  const friends = [
    { name: "friend #1" },
    { name: "friend #2" },
    { name: "friend #3" },
    { name: "friend #4" },
    { name: "friend #5" },
    { name: "friend #6" },
    { name: "friend #7" },
    { name: "friend #8" },
  ];

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        keyExtractor={(friend) => friend.name}
        data={friends}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return <Text>{item.name}</Text>;
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

Here, a warning is supposed to show if we don't add the key extractor and it goes away when we do add it. That is what happens in React Native CLI. But that does not happen in Expo CLI. Is this a bug or is it supposed to be that way in Expo? I'm running the app on an actual phone with android 7.

Answer (score 1):

The warning you are getting means that the elements of the list are missing keys. These unique keys are what allow the Flatlist to track items.
You will have to choose a unique key prop , by adding an other key field to your friends array.

you are still getting a warnning cause the key extractor falls back to use index by default

for Example :

```
 keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
```

Inside the FlatList component :

```
<FlatList
         keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
         data={friends}
         renderItem={({ item }) => {
         return <Text>{item.name}</Text>;
        }}
      />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get what the problem is and I understood your solution but it didn't help. Now I'm sure that this is a bug that is present in the android expo app. It doesn't happen with just the missing keys warning in FlatList but every single warning that my code gets. The warning doesn't go after fixing the issue in code and saving instead I need to reload the app again to make it go. And this issue is not present in React Native CLI, just Expo.

Comment: you can try updating the expo version to the latesst one , then use the command npm start -c to clear the cache